# Pick values from a CDF curve

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, cdf, ecdf

everyone,
I have a generic values distribution. I post the graph.

[image]

Is there a way to generate a CDF from these values? Using sns I can create a graph:

[image]

My goal is to assign a value to the y-axis and take a value from the x-axis from the CDF. I'm searching online but can't find a method that doesn't require going through curve normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact data format, but something like `numpy.cumsum` will take a numpy array that represents a PDF and turn it into an array that represents the CDF.

From there, with your array of `p` and `cdf` it is straightforward to find the `p` value that gives the `cdf` (which is what I understand you are looking for) with some interpolation with "nearest" as the type of interpolation (see the documentation on `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` for example).